# How to solve bootstrap server error on iPhone?

Tags: iphone

> Couldn't register com.yourcompany.accessgalary with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
>   This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.

Comment: it is the kind of thing that gets fixed by resetting the machine you're working on.

Comment: Restart device and xcode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart both simulator and Xcode, that way only you can solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete application from device
2. Reset device
3. install application now